# How to access object methods after deepclone?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am assigning the data returned from back-end service to a local object. One of my other component then tries to access a method in this class.

My Service -

```
getAllStudents(): Observable<StudentData[]> {

    Students: StudentData[];

    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(
      (rslt: any) => {
        this.Students = _.cloneDeep(rslt.Students);
        return this.Students; 
      },
      (error) => {
        throw error;
      }
    ));
```

Component -

```
service.Students.GetSomething();   <-- This is error. Says this is not a function.
```

Comment: You should show us your `cloneDeep` method

Comment: is `rslt.Students` received from server?

Comment: @XardasLord `cloneDeep` is a method from `lodash` library.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543544/trying-to-add-a-computed-property-to-a-result-set-from-a-controller-in-angular/57543603#57543603

Comment: The response always contains json data only not the functions from created class. The functions needs to be defined in a class at client side. Then you ll need to assign the received JSON to client side object.

Comment: @PareshLomate ok .. So, I just need to loop through the response and call construct the object array

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the link. The explanation was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response always contains json data only not the functions from created class. The functions needs to be defined in a class at client side. Then you ll need to assign the received JSON to client side object.

Dont consider it will work same as other programming language such as Java, as Typescript is just illusion over Javascript :). internally everything works same as Javascript.

```
class Demo {
   field: string;

   fun() { }
}

// assign response to created object
// suppose response is {
//   field: 'some text'
// }

let demo = new Demo();
// assign your values here
demo.field = res.field;
demo.fun();
```